# Google Application Script QUERY "Formula Parse Error"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

GAS novice here, but enjoying it.

Here is a data sample in a Google Sheet called "Sheet1".

[image]

I have a Google Script that formats this data, creates a new sheet called "totals by account" that sets "A1" to the formula: =QUERY(Sheet1!A:J,'select E, sum(J) group by E',0)"

This all works well, but the cell/Query gives a "Forumla parse error" message.  I've seen this Query work before, but it doesn't seem to be consistent.  I formatted column J to a number and "0.00" (DATA_SHEET.getRange("J1:J1000").setNumberFormat("0.00");)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing quotes with double quotes in the query :

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:J,"select E, sum(J) group by E",0)
```

Comment: That worked.  Thank you!  I added it to variable before setting the formula in code as well.  That helped with the string quotes.

Comment: var queryformula = '=QUERY(Sheet1!A:J,"select E, sum(J) group by E",0)';
   
formulacell.setFormula(queryformula);